# SQL From Excel VBA: Create a temporary table in VBA (for reuse) from a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I have been going nuts looking for a straightforward way to do this, but most answers I have come across go off on a tangent instead of directly addressing the question.

Here is a simplified SQL snippet I am trying to run through VBA

```
SELECT * INTO ##Customers FROM Addresses 
SELECT * FROM ##Customers a LEFT JOIN PostageRate b ON a.ZipCode=b.ZipCode
```

And then I need to put all this data into an Excel sheet.

So far I am able to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM Addresses
```

This is the functional equivalent of the first query without the temporary table. I land up with a `RecordSet` which I then put into a sheet using `CopyFromRecordSet`, but I don't know how to turn this `RecordSet` into a table so I can query it for the second query where I do the **LEFT JOIN** and then put the resulting `RecordSet` on the sheet.

Naturally the queries I am trying to run are more complex than this one, but this illustrates what I am trying to achieve.

Apologies if I have missed a post that does answer this, but I have yet to come across it.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I have looked into putting the data from the first query onto a sheet and treating the sheet as a table for the second query. The problem is as follows: 
The sheet is local and the second table is on a database. According to [this question](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/861151-how-excel-visual-basic-applications-using-sql-perform-left-join-local-named-table-database-adodb-table.html), the database would need to have access to the Excel sheet. It does not. Any more insights about how to achieve temporary tables through VBA would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: You can query excel sheets via ADODB with the ACE.OLEDB provider. The sheets are tables.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just use a subquery,  or have a table value function that builds a temporary table.  Why do you need the temporary table to exist in excel?  I guess it would make sense if your second query was on a different datasource...

Comment: @JeffUK I wouldn't mind if the temp table is created in the DB server instead of a local table. Could you point me in the right direction to doing that via Excel VBA? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @jivko I guess I could do that. I was hoping to get it all done in memory instead of spitting in on a sheet before using it. I don't have a good logical basis for my thought process though, it just felt... inelegant... 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would say, create a view in the server, and then query the view and import in excel. I'd use the database tools as much as possible if I was to do anything complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * from [Addresses]) AS Customer 
LEFT JOIN PostageRate 
ON (customer.zipcode = PostageRate.zipcode)
```